# Web visualization libraries

Tags: data-visualization, protovis

What are some good visualization libraries for online use? Are they easy to use and is there good documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO, **[Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)** is the best and is very well documented and supported.  It is the basis for my [webvis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webvis/index.html) R package.

These are also very good, although they have more of a learning curve:

- [Processing](http://www.processing.org/)
- [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/)

Comment: Protovis looks awesome but do you know what browser support it has? particularly IE?

Comment: That's unfortunately one of Protovis's weak points (but it's an issue with any SVG library because IE doesn't support that).  Fortunately, Jamie Love has come up with a solution using SVGWeb.  See here: http://groups.google.com/group/protovis/browse_thread/thread/1a80f98a16736658?pli=1.

Comment: IE 9 will also support SVG- so as long as you don't need to work with IE 6...

Comment: [d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) is the successor to protovis.

Answer (score 5):

[RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) can do some pretty amazing stuff and it just got some major backing from [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) (formerly ExtJS).  Raphael is pretty smart about browsers by using a VML backend for Internet Explorer and SVG for everything else.  However, the library is pretty low-level.  Fortunately, the author has started another project, [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/), that focuses on drawing charts and graphs.

The [MIT SIMILE Project](http://simile.mit.edu/) also has some interesting JavaScript libraries:

- [Timeplot](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeplot/)
- [Timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/)

There is also a project to port Processing to JavaScript: [ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/)

[Jmol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/) is a Java applet for viewing chemical structures, but it is used as the display engine for 3D graphics in the [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/) system, which has a completely browser-based GUI.

And for an open source alternative to Google Maps, there is the excellent [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org) JavaScript library which powers the frontend of the equally excellent [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

Answer (score 3):

- http://insideria.com/2009/12/28-rich-data-visualization-too.html 28 Rich Data Visualization Tools
- http://www.rgraph.net/ R graph
- http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of them. Here is a useful review of some twenty of them:
 http://bigdata-madesimple.com/review-of-20-best-big-data-visualization-tools/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/), it's simple, beauty and well supported.